# Add service pack number to c# winforms program i.e. 1.0.0.0 SP1

Tags: c#, winforms, exe

Is there a way to add an SP number to a c# winforms exe?

I have a number of versions of software and the company I work for uses SPx in their versions for providing service packs.

Visual Studio and the built-in version control does not like SP numbers but is there a way to provide a SP number - perhaps by changing the EXE file's version detail after compilation?

Comment: Aren't version *numbers* called *numbers* for a reason?

Comment: That's probably why the version is called 'File Version' and not 'File Version Number'.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the built-in version control" and why does it not "like" what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute` allows you to use any arbitrary string, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute.aspx

The `AssemblyVersionAttribute` does not.

So one option is to write

```
[assembly:AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly:AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("1.0.0.0 SP1")]
```

You could also use the `AssemblyInformationalAttribute`. This will be embedded in the product version field of the module.

That being said, you might want to consider *semantic versioning*. See for example http://blogs.u2u.be/kris/post/2007/05/30/Versioning-NET-Assemblies.aspx or http://semver.org/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm kind of in a situation of 'this is how we want it done' so I think the AssemblyFileVersionAttribute will resolve the issue for me.